# Cavalier having trouble keeping Trifexis down

Tags: dogs

I've got a sweet Cavvie boy in South Florida, which means that biting critters are a year-round concern. I'm giving him the appropriate Trifexis dose for his weight.

Despite the smell, he wolfs it down without any complaint whatsoever. He tends to throw it up within the hour, and the vomit smells very strongly of the Trifexis, so it's not likely he digested very much of the active ingredients. On a full stomach or an empty one, it seems to be a crapshoot whether or not he actually keeps the pill down. I've also tried halving the pill and giving him half in the morning and half at night, but he throws it up more often than not.

**Does anybody have any suggestions to keep his stomach under control after I've given him the Trifexis?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you giving the Trifexis to your dog with a meal or by itself?

From http://www.trifexis.com/about-trifexis/dosing-administration:

https://youtu.be/r4no5UzPH_4

> The most common adverse reactions reported are vomiting, depression/lethargy, itching, decreased appetite, and diarrhea. To ensure heartworm prevention, observe your dog for one hour after administration. If vomiting occurs within an hour of administration, redose with another full dose. Puppies less than 14 weeks of age may experience a higher rate of vomiting.

If your dog is unable to take the medicine without vomiting, then you will need to speak with your vet about alternative treatment options for [fleas, heartworm, and intestinal parasites](http://www.trifexis.com/about-trifexis/why-trifexis) (adult hookworm, roundworm and whipworm infections). Someone else here mentioned that speaking with whomever you got the dog from might be a good idea since they might know what works well with that breed and in your area.

When you see your veterinarian next, ask if it might be helpful to feed your dog the medicine with any food supplements. Also, it might be worth timing the medicine with her exercise routine (before or after?) As it is a monthly pill, perhaps it might help to skip a meal and not feed your dog prior to administering the medicine. Just guessing.

For what it is worth, my Lab/Goldy (~95lbs) is normally in the habit of eating grass. I have read that this helps with digestion (but it might just be something with bigger dogs). She prefers younger, tender blades. In the Winter when grass is not available, I will often add chopped parsley to her kibble. Sometimes wheat grass (like the kind used in juices, young, tender blades). Also, if she has diarrhea, I will sometimes add a TBSP of pumpkin puree (no additives, seasonings, spices, preservatives - just 100% pumpkin) to her kibble to help her get regular. Also, I will give her a TBSP of chamomile tea. Also, a little bit of rice seems to help keep her regular. A vet also once suggested a bland diet of skinless chicken, rice, pumpkin and cottage cheese when she had bad diarrhea for the first time. You might also see if getting him more water helps - possibly giving him ice cubes of chips to lick at? Possibly just feeding him the pill with his regular kibble and some sodium free chicken broth?

The above suggestions are more for dealing with digestion problems after the fact, but I figure it is worth asking your vet to see if they can help keep you Cavalier's digestion from going in reverse. Lastly, it has aspirin in it, so do not use without consulting your vet, but a small amount of [Pepto Bismol](https://pethelpful.com/dogs/Home-remedies-for-vomitng-dogs) might help. Considering your digs size, likely only a very small amount (like a teaspoon - 5mL or a half teaspoon)

Comment: I give it typically 30-60 minutes after a meal. He eats it out of my hand even more enthusiastically than the Labrador in that video @ 0:14. This month's dose he kept down. The past couple he didn't. Success rate is variable

Comment: It seems like there's a sweet spot. If it's too soon or too late after, he throws it up. I'm just wondering if anyone else has had this trouble and came up with a strategy for keeping his stomach under control. He has an appointment with a vet soon for an unrelated reason, so I'll be sure to ask the vet, also.

Comment: @sleddog hope your vet has some good suggestions or alternatives. See my edits for some suggestions, best!

Comment: Thanks for all the input. He's not a picky eater, so I'll give some of those options a judicious attempt for his April dosage.

Answer (score 3):

Medications generally have side effects; some mild, some can create worse issues than the condition being treating.

Your cavvie's rejecting *this* med, Trifexis*, which has nausea as side-effect. Rather than force the issue, I would switch to a different product. My cat and dog both use [Comfortis](https://www.comfortis.com/about-comfortis/) and tolerate it well.

*There is some [controversy](http://www.snopes.com/critters/crusader/trifexis.asp) about this medication.

Comment: +1 Some dogs don't do well with Trifexis.  If your pup is consistently having this reaction, please speak with your vet about alternatives.  Additionally, if you got your pup through a reputable breeder you should mention this to him/her since I've seen negative reactions to Trifexis correlate with bloodline (so there may or may not be a genetic component to the reactivity - con't say since this is my own anecdotal evidence/experience).

Comment: Additionally, I would contact the company and ask for a refund. Don't take "no" for an answer. I have had luck with getting my money returned when I send the unused portion back to the company.

Answer (score 2):

Vomiting is listed as a possible side-effect of [Trifexis](http://www.petmd.com/pet-medication/trifexis-spinosad-plus-milbemycin-oxime). Although I have kept dogs in the past, control of parasites was never much of a problem, so I cannot give you direct advice. However, you might consider administering a two-part treatment. I am currently giving my cat [Stronghold](https://www.petmeds.co.uk/Stronghold-Spot-On-for-Dogs/p/I0046152) for control of fleas (which is applied topically), and [Milbemax](https://www.petdrugsonline.co.uk/dogs/wormers/tablets/milbemax-dog-wormer-(adult)) as a broad-spectrum worm-killer (which is administered orally). He tolerates both well. Canine formulations are available (and the links point to these). Stronghold also kills worms (but not tapeworms), apparently. Depending on your dog's diet, it might be safe to forego tapeworm protection, since they are fairly easy to detect. Whatever you decide to do, consult a vet first. Milbemax is only available by veterinary prescription in the UK.

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy [Helminths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helminths) seem to be something of a catch-all catergory. It includes flatworms (e.g. tapeworms) and roundworms (such as heartworms). It also includes leeches. I simply used the term because I've seen it used elsewhere. I'm not pretending to be an expert. I suppose I could have used vermicide or worm-killer, although wormicide sounds pretty cool.

Comment: Gotcha, I looked up Milbemax and it does indeed treat heartworms - thanks!

Comment: @Mr.Kennedy My doctor hates it when I try to use long words, but I like to see him wince.